# Unable to connect device over Wifi for deployment of Xamarin.Android project in Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 7

Tags: deployment, xamarin.android, wifi

I want to deploy a Xamarin.Android project on a real device over Wifi in Windows 7. I am following the `Connecting over WiFi` part from the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/set-up-device-for-development

When I connect the device to the PC vía USB cable and run the command `adb tcpip 5555` in the cmd I get `error : device not found`. I looked for solutions in the internet for the problem but none of them worked. By the way my Device Manager looks like that :

[image]

The ADB Interface has exclamation mark on it. I don't know if that has anything to do with the problem.

Comment: ,restart ADB so that it using TCP on port 5555, if this command is issue, your computer will not be able to listen to devices that are connected via USB, so please check it again.

Comment: How do I restart adb? And I didn't understand the rest of the sentence `if this command is issue, your computer will not be able to listen to devices that are connected via USB, so please check it again.`. Can you give me more details?

Comment: @Piro, About restarting ADB, you can take a look:https://gist.github.com/senpost/3222887